# How to fix Tableau Aggregation issue

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field, tableau-desktop

How can I resolve error below
Error: "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function."

From calculated field:
SQRT(SUM([CUSTOMER_CNT]*([COMMS] - [Weighted average comms])^2)/(((SUM([Number of Records])-1)/SUM([Number of Records])) * SUM([CUSTOMER_CNT])))

Where Weighted average comms is the only other calculated field:
SUM([CUSTOMER_CNT] * [COMMS])/SUM([CUSTOMER_CNT])

While wrapping weighted average comms in fixed{} gets rid of the error, the output is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the first part is the issue. Missing a closing paren on [CUSTOMER_CNT] and [COMMS] is missing an aggregation.

> SQRT(SUM([CUSTOMER_CNT]*([COMMS] - [Weighted average comms])^2)

Try:

> SQRT(SUM(([CUSTOMER_CNT])*(SUM([COMMS]) - [Weighted average comms])^2)

The [Weight average comms] may also need adjustment. Usually both measures are aggregated but that could depend on the level of detail desired.

> (SUM([CUSTOMER_CNT]) * SUM([COMMS]))/SUM([CUSTOMER_CNT])